Arbitrary first and second moment for squeezed spin coherent state
Consider a spin coherent state of $N$ spin-$1/2$ atoms polarized in the $+x$-direction, denoted $\lvert \frac{\pi}{2},0 \rangle$. Now, squeeze this state in the $+z$-direction with a one-axis twisting Hamiltonian $H_z(\chi) := \hbar\chi S_z^2$ for some time $t$. What are the arbitrary first and second moments
$$\langle S_{\theta,\phi}\rangle :=\langle \frac{\pi}{2}, 0\lvert e^{it\chi S_z^2}S_{\theta, \phi}e^{-it\chi S_z^2}\lvert\frac{\pi}{2},0\rangle, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\langle S_{\theta,\phi}^2 \rangle := \langle \frac{\pi}{2}, 0\lvert e^{it\chi S_z^2}S^2_{\theta, \phi}e^{-it\chi S_z^2}\lvert\frac{\pi}{2},0\rangle. \tag{2}$$

Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be computed solely by using formulas from the appendix of Kitawaga & Ueda (1993)$^{1}$. We obtain$^2$
$$\langle S_{\theta, \phi} \rangle = \sin\theta \cos\phi \biggl( \frac{N}{2}\cos^{N-1}(\chi t) \biggr),$$
and
$$\langle S^2_{\theta,\phi} \rangle = \sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi \biggl[ \frac{N^2}{4} - \biggl( 
    \frac{N^2}{8} - \frac{N}{8} \biggr)A \biggr] \\
    + \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi \biggl[ \frac{N}{4} + \frac{N}{4}\biggl(\frac{N}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\biggr) \biggl( A + \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\cos(2\delta) \biggr) \biggr] \\
    + \cos^2\theta \biggl[ \frac{N}{4} + \frac{N}{4}\biggl(\frac{N}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\biggr) \biggl( A - \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\cos(2\delta) \biggr) \biggr] \\
    + \sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\theta \biggl[ \biggl(\frac{N^2}{2}-\frac{N}{2}\biggr)\cos^{N-2}(\chi t) \sin(\chi t) \biggr]$$
where $A := 1 - \cos^{N-2}(2\chi t)$, $B := 4\sin(\chi t) \cos^{N-2}(\chi t)$, and $\delta := \frac{1}{2}\arctan(\frac{B}{A})$.


"Squeezed spin states", Kitagawa & Ueda, 1993.

Computations done in personal notes.


